# enlarge @android:drawable/ic_menu_add icon

Tags: android, menu

I am new to Android. I need to increase the size of plus icon in main menu.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_new_photo"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:icon="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add"
    android:orderInCategory="0"
    android:title="@string/add"
    app:showAsAction="always" />
</menu>
```

What property should I add to enlarge the existing menu icon `"ic_menu_add"` icon a little bit bigger?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using the drawable vector icon you can increase the size of plus icon like this:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:width="24dp"
    android:height="24dp"
    android:viewportWidth="24.0"
    android:viewportHeight="24.0">
  <path
    android:fillColor="#FF000000"
    android:pathData="M19.35,10.04C18.67,6.59 15.64,4 12,4 9.11,4 6.6,5.64 5.35,8.04 2.34,8.36 0,10.91 0,14c0,3.31 2.69,6 6,6h13c2.76,0 5,-2.24 5,-5 0,-2.64 -2.05,-4.78 -4.65,-4.96z"/>
</vector>
```

change icon width and height as pr your requirement

**OR**

If you are not using a drawable vector icon you can download the icon as pr you choice all icons are available in this site and size is also available 24/32/64 like this please try this

https://www.flaticon.com/search?word=plus